# Rename levels in multiple specific factors in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have dataframe `DF`:

```
DF <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No")),
                 V2 = factor(c("Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No")),
                 Location = factor(c("London", "Paris", "No", "Dallas", "No")),
                 V3 = factor(c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No")),
                 V4 = factor(c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No")))
```

I want to change the values `"No"` in variables `V1`, `V2`, `V3`, and `V4` - but not `Location` - to `"X"`. I can easily change the names of levels manually in every single column, but that's time-consuming in a large dataset. However, if I use `revalue`, then every single `"No"`, including those in `Location`, which I want to remain unchanged, is changed to `"X"`:

```
library("plyr")
as.data.frame(lapply(DF, function(x) { revalue(x, c("No"="X")) }))
```

Is there a way to specify the variables based on their position in the dataset (here columns 1:2 and 4:5) to which renaming applies?

Comment: Just a note:  `data.frame` notoriously converts strings to factors by default, so the `factor()` part of your example is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the column numbers you want to apply the `revalue` function to:

```
cols_to_update <- c(1:2,4:5)
DF[, cols_to_update] <- lapply(DF[,cols_to_update], function(x) plyr::revalue(x, c("No"="X")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution using dplyrs [quosure style lambda](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/scoped.html) `~ fun(.)` as `.funs` argument combined with [forcats](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/)::fct_recode:

```r
library("dplyr")
library("forcats")

(DF <- DF %>%
    mutate_at(vars(-Location), ~fct_recode(., "X" = "No")))

#    V1  V2 Location  V3  V4
# 1 Yes Yes   London   X   X
# 2   X   X    Paris Yes Yes
# 3 Yes   X       No   X   X
# 4   X Yes   Dallas   X   X
# 5   X   X       No   X   X
```

**Update for dplyr 1.0:**

The new `across()` supersedes the family of "scoped variants" like `mutate_at`.
`across()` makes it easy to apply the same transformation to multiple columns, allowing you to use select() semantics inside in summarise() and mutate()

Applied to question here, below are 2 variations to achieve this:

```
DF %>%
  mutate(across((!Location), ~fct_recode(., "X" = "No")))

DF %>%
  mutate(across(c(1:2,4:5), ~fct_recode(., "X" = "No")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps someone can suggest a more elegant solution, however a solution that works (without manually changing every variable) is the following:

```
change.vec = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")

for(i in 1:length(change.vec)) {
    levels(DF[,change.vec[i]]) = c("X", "Yes")  
}

>DF
 V1  V2 Location  V3  V4
 1 Yes Yes   London   X   X
 2   X   X    Paris Yes Yes
 3 Yes   X       No   X   X
 4   X Yes   Dallas   X   X
 5   X   X       No   X   X
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using the tidyverse approach:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(plyr)
#> -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> You have loaded plyr after dplyr - this is likely to cause problems.
#> If you need functions from both plyr and dplyr, please load plyr first, then dplyr:
#> library(plyr); library(dplyr)
#> -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'plyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     arrange, count, desc, failwith, id, mutate, rename, summarise,
#>     summarize
DF <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No")),
                 V2 = factor(c("Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No")),
                 Location = factor(c("London", "Paris", "No", "Dallas", "No")),
                 V3 = factor(c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No")),
                 V4 = factor(c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No")))
(DF <- DF %>%
    mutate_at(.vars = vars(-Location),
              .funs = function(t) revalue(x = t,
                                          replace = c("No" = "X"))))
#>    V1  V2 Location  V3  V4
#> 1 Yes Yes   London   X   X
#> 2   X   X    Paris Yes Yes
#> 3 Yes   X       No   X   X
#> 4   X Yes   Dallas   X   X
#> 5   X   X       No   X   X
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>